# Why is create comment using Github API failing?

Tags: github, request

I have been using the GitHub Api for a couple of weeks.  Today I attempted to create a new comment using:

```
var posturi = "https://api.github.com/repos/" + owner + '/' 
      + repo + "/issues/" + number + '/comments' 
      + '?client_id=xxxxx' + '&client_secret=xxxxx' + '&access_token=xxxxxxx';
var headers = { 'user-agent': 'node.js' };
request({
  uri: posturi,
  method: "POST",
  headers: headers,
  body: comment
}, function (error, response, body) {
   ...
}
```

I know I have write authority, etc... From https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment this seems correct.
But this fails with 404!! Why?
I have tried to do this request in a few ways, with no success.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a typo?

```
var posturi = "https://api.github.com/repos/" + owner + '/' 
      + repo + "/issues/" + number + '/comments' 
      + '?client_id=xxxxx' + '&client_secret=xxxxx' + '&access_token=xxxxxxx';
```

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the issue... I have fixed my original post! which was simplified from my code.

Comment: I have asked github support and if I receive an answer I will report back.

Comment: Github suggested I try: curl -v -XPOST "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number/comments?access_token=:token" -d '{ "body": "comment" }'
BUT this is still failing and so awaiting their response.

Comment: See the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with Github support, I learned that I also needed to have the 'public_repo' scope.  I hope this helps others.  Note: you set the scope when you get the access token.